# A subgroup of order $6$ of $U_{700}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find a subgroup of order $6$ in $U_{700}$?

I got that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{240}$.

So it has a unique subgroup of order $6$. But the question is how this group looks like?

Comment: I wanted to type those digits as suffixes but can't.

Comment: If the subscript has more than one character, you need to surround it with curly brackets: i.e. U_{(700)}.

Comment: Do you mean subscripts, not suffixes?  You don't need the parentheses inside the braces if you don't want them.  \Bbb Z_{240} gives $\Bbb Z_{240}$

Comment: Given that $\phi(700)=240$, I'm guessing that $U_{700} = (\mathbb{Z}_{700})^\times$. But in this case surely we need to re-think whether $U_{700}\cong \Bbb Z_{240}$.

Comment: @Sean: $U_n$ is often used to indicate the units of the ring $\Bbb Z_n$, which is of course $(\Bbb Z_n)^\times.$

Comment: @Ross: The OP attempted to accomplish the task of the braces with parentheses only. Matt left the parentheses in the braces in his edit.

Comment: @math89 Your assertion $U_{700} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{240}$ is not correct. We know $\mathbb{Z}_{700} \cong \mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_{25}\times\mathbb{Z}_7$ (as rings) by the Chinese remainder theorem, so $U_{700}\cong U_4 \times U_{25} \times U_7$. Note the last factor has order $6$! Therefore, suggestion: (i) find an element of order $6$ in $U_7$, (ii) can you use this and the Chinese remainder theorem to find an element of order $6$ in $U_{700}$?

Comment: @SeanEberhard, I think it must be $\,\Bbb Z_2\,$ and not $\,\Bbb Z_4\,$ there...

Comment: @SeanEberhard, the elements 3 and 5 are of order 6 in $U_7$. Now what is the next step?

Comment: @math89 You found an element of order $6$ in $U_7$, good. Now find an element of order $6$ in $U_4\times U_{25}\times U_7$: this will be of the form $(a,b,c)$ where $0\leq a<4, 0\leq b<25, 0\leq c<7$. Finally use the Chinese remainder theorem to solve $x\equiv a\pmod{4},x\equiv b\pmod{25},x\equiv c\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_{700}^\times$ is not isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{240}$, since this would imply that there are primitive roots $\mod 700$.

That said, you can still find a subgroup of order 6 in  $\mathbb{Z}_{700}^\times$. It will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$. So all you have to do is find an element of order 6.

Comment: I just now read the Carnichael function,I don't know enough of it.Now I think that all the elements i.e. {1,2,3,4,5,6} of $U_7$ are of order 6.So from this I guess that all the elements in $U_n$, in which case $U_n$ is cyclic, are of order $\lambda (n)$. and there is no element of order 6 in $U_4$ and $U_{25}$, as all the elements in $U_4$ and $U_{25}$ are of order 4 and 20 respectively.So after this how can I proceed? @  Sean Eberhard, Hans Engler

Comment: Try subgroups generated by $x = 50k \pm 1$ for various values of $k$.